# How to send my array to my api

Tags: cakephp, httpclient

I'm stuck trying to transfer my array($conditions) to my api(@pagination_condition). Anybody has any clues. Thanks
Client code:

```
$tofind = $this->request->query;
$conditions = array( `enter code here`
                        array( 
                        "TransactionInfo.created >= " => "$startDate_finder", 
                        "TransactionInfo.created <=" => "$endDate_finder" 
                        ), 
                        "OR" => array( 
                        array( "User.first_name LIKE " => "%$keyword_finder%" ),
                        array( "User.last_name LIKE " => "%$keyword_finder%" )
                        ),
                        "ORDER" => array("TransactionInfo.created" => "desc"),
                        "limit" => 30
                      );
        $response = json_decode($this->HTTPClient->get($this->apiUrl . "users/search/page:{$query}.json", $tofind."&condition="json_encode($conditions)), true);
```

My api Code:

```
if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $finder = $this->request->query;
        $pagination_conditions = array(
            'conditions' => null, //array('Model.field' => $thisValue), //array of conditions
            'recursive' => 1, //int
            'fields' => null, //array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'), //array of field names
            'order' => null, //array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'), //string or array defining order
            'group' => null, //array('Model.field'), //fields to GROUP BY
            'limit' => null, //n, //int
            'page' => null, //n, //int
            'offset' => null, //n, //int
            'callbacks' => true, //true //other possible values are false, 'before', 'after'
        );
        $pagination_conditions = array_merge($pagination_conditions, json_decode($conditions));
```

I want the condition array set at the client to overwrite the pagination_condition in the api. Your clue(s) will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now, with that code, what's the problem? Does it give you any errors? Are the conditions not via get? Or are they but the merge is not what you want? With the code you posted, I can't see where you define the `$conditions` variable or how you're sending the encoded data, so it's difficult to help without knowing the error or having a bit more of code.

Comment: Just edited the code. I'm kind of new to this and i can't see the error thrown by the api even in the log file. Just need a snippet on how to send an array across via httpclient. Thanks